# rearrange the array with the $.map

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have list and inside  bunch of the object.My list looks like this

[image]

What I want to do is return an list which contains the objects something like this

```
var list =[{Price:250,Id:2},{Content:"content here",Id:1},......]
```

I am using $.map but seems not working.
here is the what I have tried so far

```
 var dt=   $.map(lst.rows,function(val,key) {
                     var newobj;
                     if (key=="Name") {
                          eval("key."+val);
                     }

                     return newobj;

                 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** or **[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** for iterating array

```js
var lst={rows:[{Name:'a',Value:1,Id:1},{Name:'b',Value:5,Id:2},{Name:'c',Value:451,Id:3}]}

var dt = lst.rows.map(function(val, key) {
  var tmp = {};
  tmp[val.Name] = val.Value;
  tmp['id'] = val.Id;
  return tmp;
});

console.log(dt);
```

or

```js
var lst={rows:[{Name:'a',Value:1,Id:1},{Name:'b',Value:5,Id:2},{Name:'c',Value:451,Id:3}]}

var dt = $.map(lst.rows,function(val, key) {
  var tmp = {};
  tmp[val.Name] = val.Value;
  tmp['id'] = val.Id;
  return tmp;
});

console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```